# How do you go about adding React.js plus its dependencies in an external website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I'm helping a buddy build out his website. He does not currently have anything React related in his tech stack. I used npm's create-react-app to build out a component for him, so everything was already setup for me... and now its time to integrate into his site.

This is my weakest part of development, and I am a bit confused on how to make sure he has all the dependencies and packages he needs to use my React component. I've read React's docs, but it's somewhat vague.

So for example I wrote in JSX so he needs Babel or something similar to interpret this syntax. I also used the CSS preprocessor SASS so this will need this to be installed as well, along with other npm packages such as Axios for API calls and ResizeObserver. I believe create-react-app uses Webpack too for bundling which also seems necessary in production websites.

I'm looking for a high level overview of how someone would go about this process of getting him the correct dependencies and also handing over my React component in the neatest way possible to integrate.

Thanks a ton I really appreciate any tips and insight.

Comment: does your react component have styles associated with it? are they separate in a css file or are they inline styles in the css?

Comment: if you've made a 'create-react-app' application, it's totally possible to output the javascript with `npm run build` and just hand him that, as long as you've added either a globally accessible function to trigger a render, or you can count on there being something in the page to render your component into before your js file runs.

Comment: Create a production build: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/ He needs to include react and then bind your component to dom.

Comment: you (probably) wouldn't even need him to worry about webpack, babel or any external dependences as long as your create-react-app application had them all sorted beforehand

Comment: @TKoL There is an external style sheet that houses the styles. It's a big .scss file.

Comment: in that case, he'd need the compiled stylesheet too

Comment: It really depends on your component and how you expect a user to interact with it. Does he call a function and pass the function an element to render your component into that element? Or will it render itself into matching elements when your .js file runs?

Comment: @TKoL I’m actually handing him a React component where the parent is a button that launches a modal I built. This parent component is the one looking for an ID in the DOM to hook on to which will place the button on his site. It sounds like that npm run build will wrap all the necessary packages and dependencies needed for React. When I hand him this built package, where in the file structure would a built package like this belong?

Comment: @mkaatman This is amazing thank you! When you say include react in the dom, do you mean by adding <script> tags in the header that link to the react package?

Comment: Include your script that includes something like: `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("application"));`